# asp razor error with html tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I tried to use foreach loop and some if statements in asp mvc razor view. But it gives shows error.

```
@{
    int modalNumber = 0;
    foreach (var articleList in ViewBag.articleList)
    {
        if ((modalNumber % 4) == 0)
        {
            <div class="item">
        }
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="article-box text-center">                                        
                <div>@articleList.NewsPaperName</div>
                <div>@articleList.DateCode</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        modalNumber=modalNumber+1;
        if((modalNumber % 4)==0)
        {
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

It shows this inside html page

```
} modalNumber=modalNumber+1; if((modalNumber % 4)==0) {
```

[image]
How to solve this issue.

Comment: After an HTML block, you'll have to start a code block again. Try reading a Razor tutorial.

Comment: The issue is the way you mixing razor and html. If you use `@:<div class="item">` it may work (ditto in the 2nd `if` block). But there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036634/unbalanced-div-closing-div-with-mvc-razor-for-each-loop/41053100#41053100) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
@modalNumber=modalNumber+1;

@if ((modalNumber % 4) == 0)
{
   @Html.Raw("</div");
})
```